# Completar campos a partir de um campo com mascara

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma função que completa os campos `tipo logradouro, endereço, bairro, cidade e estado` a partir do momento que o usuário informa o `cep`. Porém tenho uma máscara no campo CEP, e como os registros no banco de dados estão sem caracteres, ela não retorna os dados.

Tenho 2 dúvidas

1ª: existe possibilidade de eu conseguir preencher os campos a partir do CEP com máscara?

2ª: existe possibilidade de eu trazer os campos do banco de dados e a medida que eles são retornados obterem a máscara para serem exibidos com caracteres?

index.php

```html
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[name='cep']").blur(function(){
                        var $tipo_logr = $("input[name='tipo_logr']");
                        var $nome_logr = $("input[name='nome_logr']");
                        var $bairro = $("input[name='bairro']");
                        var $cidade = $("input[name='cidade']");
                        var $estado = $("input[name='estado']");
                        
                        $.getJSON('function_func.php',{ 
                                cep: $( this ).val() 
                        },function( json ){
                                $tipo_logr.val ( json.tipo_logr );
                                $nome_logr.val ( json.nome_logr );
                                $bairro.val ( json.bairro );
                                $cidade.val ( json.cidade );
                                $estado.val ( json.estado );
                        });
                });
        });    
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#cep').mask('00000-000');
            $('#fone').mask('0000-0000');
            $('#fax').mask('0000-0000');
            $('#data_nascimento').mask('00/00/0000');
        });
    </script>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4"><!-- Inicio Input CEP -->
            <label for="ex1">Cep: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='cep' name='cep' maxlength='8' placeholder='_____-___'><br>
        </div><!-- Fim Input CEP -->

        <div class="col-lg-8"><!-- Inicio Input Tipo Logradouro -->
            <label for="ex1">Tipo Logradouro: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tipo_logr" maxlength='4'><br>
        </div><!-- Fim Input Tipo Logradouro -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- Inicio Input Endereco -->
            <label for="ex1">Endereço: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_logr" maxlength='40'><br>
        </div><!-- Fim Input Endereco -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- Inicio Input Bairro -->
            <label for="ex1">Bairro: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro" maxlength='30'><br>
        </div><!-- Fim Input Bairro -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-8"><!-- Inicio Input Cidade-->
            <label for="ex1">Cidade: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cidade" maxlength='30'><br>
        </div><!-- Fim Input Cidade -->

        <div class="col-lg-4"><!-- Inicio Input Estado -->
            <label for="ex1">Estado: </label>
            <input name="estado" type="text" class="form-control" name="estado" maxlength='2'><br>
        </div><!-- Fim Input Estado -->                                
    </div>
```

function_func.php

```
<?php     

include_once("conn.php");

function ret($cep, $conn){

    $result = "SELECT * FROM cadcep WHERE cep = '$cep' LIMIT 1";

    $resultado = $conn->query($result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    if($resultado){

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['tipo_logr'] = $row['tipo_logr'];
        $valores['nome_logr'] = $row['nome_logr'];
        $valores['bairro'] = $row['bairro'];
        $valores['cidade'] = $row['cidade'];
        $valores['estado'] = $row['estado'];


    } else {
        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
    }

        return json_encode($valores);

}

if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
        echo ret($_GET['cep'], $conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Você quer pegar o valor digitado pelo usuário com máscara e remover ela na hora de procurar no banco correto? quais campos vc devem ser mascarados no retorno?

Comment: correto isso mesmo, os campos que queria que voltassem com máscara são: fone e fax, mas quero aprender isso para usar isso caso precise futuramente

Comment: Mas o php não devolve esse campos (fone, fax etc)

Comment: esta retornando normalmente porém o usuário informa 3333-3333 na hora de inserir o registro no banco de dados, e eu elimino os caracteres para salvar e é inserido assim 33333333 sem o '-' queria saber se tem como eu trazer ele com - para exibir para o usuário, apenas uma dúvida se é possível ou não, E a outra é se eu consigo remover a máscara do campo cep na hora de procurar o registro no banco de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Para manter a máscara no campo e fazer a busca, retire os caracteres especiais dentro da função:

```
function ret($cep, $conn){

    $a_cep = str_replace(".", "", $cep);
    $b_cep = str_replace("-", "", $a_cep);
    $result = "SELECT * FROM cadcep WHERE cep = '$b_cep' LIMIT 1";
```

2 - Para definir a máscara, ordene que ela seja executada novamente após os valores terem sido preenchidos, e substitua o `'0' (indica apenas o padrão da máscara) por`'9'(indica o que o padrão é numérico)`:

```
$.getJSON('function_func.php',{ 
    cep: $( this ).val() 
},function( json ){
    $tipo_logr.val ( json.tipo_logr );
    $nome_logr.val ( json.nome_logr );
    $bairro.val ( json.bairro );
    $cidade.val ( json.cidade );
    $estado.val ( json.estado );

    $('#cep').mask('99999-999');
    $('#fone').mask('9999-9999');
    $('#fax').mask('9999-9999');
    $('#data_nascimento').mask('99/99/9999');
});
```

OBS: Pessoalmente acho o plugin https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask melhor para criar máscaras, ele mantem a formatação independente do momento do preenchimento.

Comment: Obrigado, nunca tinha visto este plugin, vou estudar a respeito . A resposta 1- funcionou, porém a 2 continua retornando com os dados sem caracteres, eu já tinha tentando desta forma e foi sem sucesso

Comment: @VictorT. tenta substituindo o '0' por '9'

Comment: agora foi, nossa não sabia dessa distinção, muito obrigado por compartilhar sua sabedoria rs

Comment: Recomendo dar uma lida na documentação , esses são detalhes simples que as vezes nem percebemos kk, atualizei a resposta com o correto, da uma lida ali, o '0' é pra indicar um padrão qualquer, o '9' serve pra indicar que é numérico, e tem alguns outros, mas não vem ao caso.

Comment: Se for usar esse plugin pode usar `$('#cep').inputmask('unmaskedvalue');` para pegar o valor sem máscara, em algumas situações é útil :)